# Xcode 7 swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: swift2, runtime-error, ios9, xcode7.1

I've downloaded code from [Apple Sample Source Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Introduction/Intro.html) and try to run on `Xcode 7.1` and `OS X 10.11.1`. I'm getting error as `SwiftC failed with exit code 1.` I've tried all solutions mentioned on [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176521/xcode-swiftc-failed-with-exit-code-11-what-can-i-do) but none worked.

[image: Screenshot for error]

Any fix?

Comment: Is there anything you need to download from within Xcode?

Comment: @trojanfoe : Nope...All I need was simulator and documentation that I downloaded it.

Comment: the code needs ios9.1 sdk

Answer (score 0):

Earlier I had three Xcode in my Mac machine viz Xcode 6.4, 7.1 and 7.1.1.
I got the earlier two version of Xcode removed from system. Thereafter I *tested Apple [3D touch Sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/ViewControllerPreviews/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016546-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) on Xcode 7.1.1* and it worked correctly.