# objc[2866]: pthread_rwlock_rdlock failed (11)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

Unexpectedly crash my app when i used to get the instance of UITableViewCell object using the following method

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))
```

**In the Xcode log showing the following bugs**

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>
> objc[2866]: task_threads failed (result 0x10004004)
>
> pthread_rwlock_rdlock failed (11)

Comment: are you initializing the cell or taking in storyboard ?

Comment: its a dynamic tableview using prototype cells

Comment: I think when "let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0))" line is executed then tableview cell is not created so crashing .

Comment: tableview loading fine
its crashing when i try to access the instance (cell is not appear in the list)

Comment: you need to do it in cellForRowAtIndex only

Comment: pls post the code for your tableview's `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to Specify the base class for the cell prototype , See below there is a custom class

CustomTableViewCell:
[image]

And also s pecify the base class for the cell prototype to be

CustomTableViewCell:

[image]

And Use below code  cellForRowAtIndexPath in your data source:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomTableViewCell

    let person = dataArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

May be it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by an Xcode build issue and may have nothing to do with the `UITableViewCell` object. Try cleaning the project and rebuilding. See [Xcode : */swiftc failed with exit code 11, what can I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32176521/xcode-swiftc-failed-with-exit-code-11-what-can-i-do)